# macro `AM_PATH_CPPUNIT' not found in library

Tags: makefile, configure, cppunit

I am trying to build `libtorrent` on shared hosting. So built CPPUnit(1.12.1) with `--prefix=$HOME`. After that my `$HOME/lib` and `$HOME/include` contains CPPUnit libraries and headers.

The I exported `LD_` paths

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_INCLUDE_PATH=$HOME/include:$LD_INCLUDE_PATH
```

Then I run `libtorrent/autogen.sh --prefix=$HOME` and getting the following warning, which prevents me to run configure:

```
aclocal...
aclocal:configure.ac:20: warning: macro `AM_PATH_CPPUNIT' not found in library
```

cppunit.m4 file is located in $HOME/share/aclocal. I guess `libtorrent` can't find that dir for some reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You installed CPPUnit in a non-system place that's not searched by default, so oddly enough when running aclocal within the libtorrent build, it didn't know to look there.  You can [tell aclocal where to look with -I](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Macro-Search-Path.html) and I'm sure you can find a way to do that with autogen.sh in the middle.

Comment: Yes, `-I` did the trick and now I got `configure:19214: error: possibly undefined macro: LT_SMP_CACHE_BYTES`.

Comment: Anyway, I'll have my own research first. Thanks for helping with this one.

Answer (score 42):

You need to do an `apt-get install libcppunit-dev`

Comment: This no longer works. cppunit.m4 was removed from libcppunit-dev.

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled across this page trying to follow the default [*cppunit Money tutorial*](http://cppunit.sourceforge.net/doc/cvs/money_example.html). As @Carlo Wood specified

> This no longer works. cppunit.m4 was removed from libcppunit-dev.

Which is true, I followed the next answer to no avail, there is no `cppunit.m4`, the error is that you don't even need AM_PATH_CPPUNIT, just use

```
ProgramName_LDADD = -lcppunit
```

instead of `ProgramName_LDFLAGS = $(CPPUNIT_LIBS)`

Furthermore, I don't know if the rest of the `Makefile.am` is actually necessary, this is the Makefile I ended up using

Makefile.am

```
TESTS = MoneyApp
bin_PROGRAMS = $(TESTS)
MoneyApp_SOURCES = ...
MoneyApp_CXXFLAGS = $(CPPUNIT_CFLAGS)
MoneyApp_LDADD = -lcppunit
```

And config.ac

```
AC_INIT([MoneyApp], 1.0)
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
AC_PROG_CC
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_CONFIG_FILES(Makefile)
AC_OUTPUT
```

Hopefully this helps somebody in the future.

Comment: Even if they don't use pkg-config for cppunit, you should still test for it with AC_CHECK_LIB([cppunit], [main]) or something like this:"""
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([CPPUNIT], [cppunit], [],
        AC_MSG_ERROR(please install library and try again -- see HACKING file))

""" so that your users get an error (or warning if you use AC_MSG_WARN) to tell them they need to install cppunit. (note that this comment feature did not let me put newlines to make it more readable)

Answer (score 1):

I try everymethod that I found in the internet. But fix it at last only when get know the root cause.

1.The AM_PATH_CPPUNIT is declared in cppunit.m4. The errors happens because the cppunit.m4 is not found.

2.command "**aclocal --version**" to find out the version. i.e. aclocal-1.15.

3.command "**find / | grep aclocal-1.15**" to find out the lib place. i.e. /usr/local/share/aclocal-1.15

4.command "find / | grep cppunit.m4" to make sure you have a cppunit.m4. if not, command "yum list *cppunit*" and install the package listed.an repeat current step.

5.copy that cppunit.m4 to the mentioned aclocal lib path.

6.run again and the error disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when building libtorrent with MSYS2 in Windows.
Installed `cppunit` package and the `autogen.sh` step completed error free.

`pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-cppunit`

or for 32bit:
`pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-cppunit`

.

Also for building `libtorrent` Windows MSYS run configure with `--disable-mincore`:

`./configure --disable-mincore`

https://rtwi.jmk.hu/wiki/rTorrentOnWindows

Answer (score 0):

At Ubuntu 18.04/bionic the @iggy12345 's solution worked perfectly.
Only had to add "touch stdafx.h" and remove -I option from aclocal (on Ubuntu it is installed in /usr/share, not in /usr/local/share).